# iOS React Native: Add build configuration other than Debug and Release

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm working on a react native project, by default they are two build configurations (Debug and Release) that works just fine. However, when i create a new build configuration by duplicating the Release configuration and then try to run the application targeting the created build configuration, i get the following error:

> fatal error: module map file 'PathToBuildFolder/Stage-iphoneos/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found

Stage is the name of the created build configuration, any idea how i can solve this ?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

If you are following Yee Wong Medium Blog and end up with this issue, I have fixed it with below solution

1. add below line in pod file

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

project '{PROJECT_NAME}', 'Dev.Debug' => :debug, 'Dev.Release' => :release  <--------- ADD THIS LINE

def add_flipper_pods!(versions = {})
```

2. Replace all the instances of 'Debug' to ['Dev.Debug', 'Dev.Release', 'Debug']

Before:

```
pod 'FlipperKit', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
```

After:

```
pod 'FlipperKit', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => ['Dev.Debug', 'Dev.Release', 'Debug']
```

// Change all the configruation =>

3. `npx pod-install`
4. select Dev scheme and run on simulator

After doing above changes my project build successfully, Refer below links for help:

1. Main medium link
   https://medium.com/@ywongcode/building-multiple-versions-of-a-react-native-app-4361252ddde5
2. https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/30

Comment: Hi please use the code highlighting feature to improve the readability of your post. Thanks

Comment: Is there something else one would need to do to run an app built with the duplicated Debug config with the metro server? I can build it successfully, but it just crashes immediately on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This is related with this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28503) 
I solved my problem with following picture

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, i tried this with the duplicated build configuration and i got the same problem.